# simulate a continuous time system in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode

I'm trying to simulate a continuous time system but i can't find a solution to this error.
I tried many days and can't figure out what is the error in the code.

Please help out .

```
clc;
Ts=0.1;
T=0:0.1:5;
N=50;
numc=[1 0.3 4 0.6 3];
denc=[1 0.3 6 1.2 10 1.2 4];
sysc=tf(numc,denc);
ud=idinput(N,'prbs',[0 0.1],[-1 1]);
x0 = [0;0;0;0];
yd=lsim(sysc,ud,T);
```

Comment: What is not working as you expect? Do you get error messages or are the results wrong? Can you show the actual output (or error message) and desired output?

Comment: I am getting this error message. Error using DynamicSystem/lsim
When simulating the response to a specific input signal,
the input data U must be a matrix with as many rows as
samples in the time vector T, and as many columns as
input channels.

Error in Q11 (line 10)
yd=lsim(sysc,ud,T);

Answer (score 0):

The **N** elements number is wrong. The length of the vector generated in `T=0:0.1:5;` must be the same that uses the idinput function.

Example:

```
clc;
Ts=0.1;
T=(0:Ts:5)';
N=length(T);
numc=[1 0.3 4 0.6 3];
denc=[1 0.3 6 1.2 10 1.2 4];
sysc=tf(numc,denc);
ud=idinput(N,'prbs',[0 0.1],[-1 1]);
x0 = [0;0;0;0];
yd=lsim(sysc,ud,T);
```

Notes:
The transpose of vector T is donne to unified dimensions for all the variables.

Comment: Thanks for that .Its worked. If we want to get N=5000 samples how do i calculate T ? could you please tell me how to calculate this ?

Comment: You can use this: `T = linspace(0, 5, N)`. Where 0 and 5 are the lower and upper limits and N the number of samples.